# Multiple resource providers in same transaction Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jackrabbit

I am using Jackrabbit to store files (data store) and Hibernate almost everything else. I do not know alot of transactions etc. but I know that I want a global transaction for these two so that an exception rolls back everything. At the moment the database stuff is rolled back, but Jackrabbit isn't.

I am using Spring 3.2. I have deployed the Jackrabbit JCA adapter to JBoss (7.1.1). I have these lines in the config xml:

```
<bean id="txManager"
      class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager"></bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"
                      proxy-target-class="true"/>
```

However that isn't enough it seems. Could somebody give me some clues to what I need to read about/where to find information on this? I need to roll back everything if something happens to one of the resource providers.

Answer (score 2):

This was quite tricky to set up. One gotcha was the spring automagically uses 'transactionManager' as a default name which caused problems. It is definitely worth the effort though as synchronising mismatched data sources would soon become a nightmare.

Here is my sample config that worked for me. Of course now we would probably use @Configuration instead of the xml. This worked using, Spring Data, JTA, MySQL with XA driver and Neo4j. Neo4j specific things have been omitted.

Spring Data may also help you here.

Here is a starter...

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="xaTransactionManager" />

<bean id="xaTransactionManager" class="some.type.of.ChainedTransactionManager">
  <constructor-arg>
    <list>
      <ref bean="jpaTransactionManager"/>
      <ref bean="otherTransactionManager"/>
    </list>
  </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="jpaTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
  <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"/>
</bean>

<bean id="otherTransactionManager" class="other.type.of.jta.TransactionManager"> 
  <property name="transactionManager" ref="otherTransactionManagerService"/>  
</bean>
```

Comment: And what would type would the `ChainedTransactionManager` be? Is it a class from Spring or what? Where can I find on?

Comment: And, I am not very good at transactions but this isn't using JBoss as a transaction manager right? How can I do that in spring?....what am I actually doing here? I am not sure I get it.

Comment: The following link might help explain a little: http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-04-2007/jw-04-xa.html

Comment: In my case it was a Neo4j based, I expect either Spring Data or JackRabbit ship with one. No this was running in plain Tomcat. You can hook into Jboss if you like, or as I prefer, use Atomikos.